# Device can't connect to Worklight Server

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I've deployed an app built with Worklight Studio 6.0 to my mobile phone.

Unfortunately I get the UNEXPECTED_ERROR code 404 when the app tries to connect to the server (inside WL Studio). See below:

```
{"status":404,"errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"Il server non è stato in grado di elaborare la richiesta dell'applicazione. Riprova più tardi."}"
```

The problem is that, speaking about the Android environment, the wlclient.properties is correctly filled up by the IP, PORT, CONTEXT ROOT:

```
wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = 192.168.0.100
wlServerPort = 10080
wlServerContext = /MyHybridApps/
wlAppId = MyMobileBanking
```

I can't understand where's the issue or what I could check in order to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you translate the message to English, please?

Comment: Have you tried visiting the endpoint you're specifying in a webbrowser? e.g. 192.168.0.100:10080/MyHybridApps/ ? Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a mistake in the config.xml file. Now the app is connected to the server. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: please provide what you changed in the config.xml because i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause would be if your computer has several network cards and the server is issued one of them, but the builder uses a different address in wlclient.properties.

try to have only 1 IP address for the computer and then re-build; the server and client should then be assigned with the same IP address.